# How to add color to ranges in sap.m.Range slider in SAP UI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a Range slider from min value 0 and Max value 100.Value 1 is 50 Value 2 is 75

I want the color to be green from 0 to 50 and yellow from 50 to 75 and Red from 75 to 100 in sap m.Rangeslider.

How can I do that.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

UI5 does not support this. The color depends on the theme you are using.
You can implement it by manipulating the css of DOM by yourself.